# Remove element from SynchronizedMultimap adds unexpected behavior

Tags: java, collections, lambda, java-8, guava

I am using a synchronized SetMultimap from Guava 18.0

The set is declared as follows

```
private SetMultimap<String, Foo> fooMultimap;

private StatusService() {
    this.fooMultimap = Multimaps.synchronizedSetMultimap(HashMultimap.<String, Foo>create());
}
```

Where the StatusService is a spring boot `@Service` which of course is treated as a singleton. The SetMultimap is a multimap containing 
where Foo is a model with several properties.

Therefore I have the following methods:

```
/* remove element */
public void removeFoo(String fooId, Foo foo) {
    fooMultimap.remove(fooId, foo);
}
```

and also

```
/* remove element by unique property(element path) */
public void removeByPath(String path) {
    Lists.newArrayList(getAllFoos().values()).stream()
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .filter(foo -> Optional.ofNullable(foo.getPath())
                        .filter(fooPath -> fooPath.contains(path))
                        .isPresent()
                ).forEach(filteredFoo -> removeFoo(img.getId(), img));
  }
}
```

and getAllFoos() method as follows

```
public SetMultimap<String, Foo> getAllFoos() {
    return this.fooMultimap;
}
```

What I am failing to understand is why Guava doesn't remove the elements from the multimap, maybe I am doing something wrong, I have tried all possible combinations as `.values()` or `.asMap()` or `.entries()` without any luck.

Can someone please explain me what is the best way to remove key, value entries from a Guava `synchronized SetMultimap` ?

---

Here is an example to reproduce my problem, if I alter an object, then I cannot remove entries anymore. The altering happens when I change the status of an Image

```
package test;

import com.google.common.collect.HashMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import com.google.common.collect.Multimaps;
import com.google.common.collect.SetMultimap;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test {


    public static SetMultimap<String, Image> mm;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        mm = Multimaps.synchronizedSetMultimap(HashMultimap.<String, Image>create());
        Image i1 = new Image("1", ImageState.DONE, "original", "path1");
        Image i2 = new Image("2", ImageState.DONE, "original", "path1");
        Image i3 = new Image("3", ImageState.DONE, "original", "path1");
        Image i4 = new Image("2", ImageState.DONE, "original", "path2");
        Image i5 = new Image("2", ImageState.DONE, "original", "path2");

        mm.put("1", i1);
        mm.put(i2.getId(), i2);
        mm.put("3", i3);
        mm.put("2", i4);
        mm.put(i5.getId(), i5);

        System.out.println("original multimap:" + mm.toString());

        // when altering an object everything goes down the drain and 
        // objects are not removed correctly as expected.
        getImageByMetadata(i2).setStatus(ImageState.PENDING);

        Image i6 = getImageByMetadata(i2);

        System.out.println(i2);
        System.out.println(i6);

        mm.remove(i6.getId(), i6);
        System.out.println("multimap should be smaller 1:" + mm.toString());

        mm.get(i6.getId()).remove(i6);
        System.out.println("multimap should be smaller 2:" + mm.toString());

        mm.asMap().get(i2.getId()).remove(i2);
        System.out.println("multimap should be smaller 3:" + mm.toString());

        removeByPath("path2");
        removeByPath("path1");
        System.out.println("should remove 2 elements:" + mm.toString());

    }

    public static Image getImageByMetadata(Image imageMetadata) {
        List<Image> images = Lists.newArrayList(mm.values());
        List<Image> filteredImage = mm.values().stream()
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .filter(image -> imageMetadata.getId().equals(image.getId()) &&
                        imageMetadata.getFormat().equals(image.getFormat()) &&
                        Optional.ofNullable(image.getPath())
                                .filter(thisPath -> thisPath.contains(imageMetadata.getPath()))
                                .isPresent()
                ).collect(Collectors.toList());

        if (filteredImage.size() == 0) {
            return new Image();
        } else {
            return filteredImage.get(0);
        }
    }

    public static void removeByPath(String path) {
        mm.get("2").stream()
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .filter(image -> Optional.ofNullable(image.getPath())
                        .filter(imagePath -> imagePath.contains(path) && image.getStatus().equals(ImageState.DONE))
                        .isPresent()
                ).forEach(img -> {
            mm.values().remove(img);
        });
    }
}

class Image {

    private String id;
    private ImageState status;
    private String format;
    private String path;

    public Image() {
    }

    public Image(String id, ImageState status, String format, String path) {
        this.id = id;
        this.status = status;
        this.format = format;
        this.path = path;
    }

    public ImageState getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public Image setStatus(ImageState status) {
        this.status = status;
        return this;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public Image setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
        return this;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String thatId) {
        id = thatId;
    }

    public String getFormat() {
        return format;
    }

    public void setFormat(String thatFormat) {
        format = thatFormat;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Image)) return false;
        Image image = (Image) o;
        return com.google.common.base.Objects.equal(id, image.id) &&
                status == image.status &&
                com.google.common.base.Objects.equal(format, image.format) &&
                com.google.common.base.Objects.equal(path, image.path);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return com.google.common.base.Objects.hashCode(id, status, format, path);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Image{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", status=" + status +
                ", format='" + format + '\'' +
                ", path='" + path + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}

enum ImageState {
    DONE, PENDING, ABORTED, NOT_FOUND
}
```

Comment: Did you verify that a) there are elements passing the filter, i.e. `removeFoo` is ever called and b) the string returned by `img.getId()` does match the key under which `img` is actually mapped? By the way, it might be simpler to use `getAllFoos().asMap().values().removeIf( foo -> Optional.ofNullable(foo) .map(Foo::getPath) .filter(fooPath -> fooPath.contains(path)) .isPresent());`…

Comment: @Holger, yes, the filter returns the matching object, but for some strange reason when I call ```fooMultimap.remove(foo.id, foo)``` the element doesn't get removed, equals and hashcode have been implemented at model level btw.

Comment: Did you check what `fooMultimap.containsEntry(foo.id, foo)` says right before the `remove` call?

Comment: @Holger that is the strange part, even though the foo instance is retrieved by doing a looking-up, the multimap returns a ```false``` on the ```.containsEntry()``` call, do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: Maybe it's not stored under `foo.id` but another key.

Comment: @zeroflagL not really, I've tried a very simple use case where I add a (k,v) pair, then I try to remove it. So at the starting point the multimap is empty.

Comment: I can’t reproduce this problem with a plain setup. There must be an irregular aspect, a change after putting, of the id or `Foo`’s equality, or a problem with `Foo`’s equality in general…

Comment: @Holger, I have added a full example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Well, it’s as suspected. You are modifying the element in a way that affects its equality. This can’t work.

Comment: @Holger I still don't understand what implementation is used under the hood, since I retrieve the reference of the modified element when trying to remove it, which it should point to the modified element. I mean the only reason this wouldn't work is only if the Multimap instance keeps the old hashcode somewhere inside and tries to remove the element based on that.

Comment: Sure. A Multimap is a kind of Map from key to Set. I’ll bet, there will be hashing involved…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a `Multimap<K,V>` is a kind of `Map<K,Set<V>>` (though not implementing it), it bears similar semantics, i.e. you must not modify elements after insertion in a way that affects their hashcode/ equality.

Besides that, you ran into the iterate-then-lookup anti-pattern. That’s not only inefficient, it can cause `ConcurrentModificationException`s when being used with iterators which don’t support modifications to the collection they are iterating upon (besides those made via the iterator itself).

In most cases, there are simple alternatives, e.g. instead of

```
public static void removeByPath(String path) {
    mm.get("2").stream()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .filter(image -> Optional.ofNullable(image.getPath())
                    .filter(imagePath -> imagePath.contains(path)
                                      && image.getStatus().equals(ImageState.DONE))
                    .isPresent()
            ).forEach(img -> {
        mm.values().remove(img);
    });
}
```

You can simply use

```
public static void removeByPath(String path) {
    mm.get("2").removeIf(
        image -> Optional.ofNullable(image).map(Image::getPath)
                .filter(imagePath -> imagePath.contains(path)
                                  && image.getStatus().equals(ImageState.DONE))
                .isPresent()
        );
}
```

which avoids the obsolete lookup and won’t throw `ConcurrentModificationException`s. Note that while this will now work, even when the hash code has changed, changing the hash code after insertion still is not a correct usage and the fact that subsequent lookups may fail should alarm you.

Comment: I have taken another path, which is kind of cheesy but it works, when I modify an element I first remove it from the Multimap and then re-insert the modified instance. Everything works well, as for the ConcurrentModificationException I am using a ```parallelStream()``` since my Multimap is ```synchronized```. Any thoughts on that ?

Comment: Well, you still have to iterate over a copy to avoid exceptions, even when the collection is `synchronized` (the problem even exists for single-threaded operations). However I doubt that you gain anything with a parallel stream when you call back into `synchronized` methods. Especially, as the most expensive operation will be the lookup here and when using an iterator-based removal or `removeIf`, you don’t have that lookup overhead at all…

Comment: Thanks, now I understand.